# Why do consequent edits on the same post bring rewards all the same?

Tags: discussion, edits, reputation

I always opposed the idea of giving reputation points for edits. A post should be edited for clarity, not reputation. For most persons the better looking text or a code is already a reward.

But it turned to be even worse. I had no idea [a blatant vandalism could be rewarded](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59014083/revisions).

[image: Reputation for vandalism]

All right, vandalism aside, but it seems the system encourages quick and dirty edits instead of rewarding a single, but complete edit. I don't get how it's even possible and what could be a reason behind rewarding consequent edits.

Is it possible to limit the rewards to a singe edit per post?

Comment: The edits just went through, because the OP accepted each of them. My impression is, the editor "just wanted to help" and the OP appreciated that. Of course, a rollback is in order, but does such an incident happen that often?

Comment: I actually wasn’t aware of this either and am somewhat surprised by it. I don’t think it’s a very serious problem, but would also question how legit it is for someone to earn more than 2 reputation from edits to the same post.

Comment: this post should be deleted or it will give some ideas to voting rings!

Comment: I'm not against someone being able to gain rep points by editing, it is also mentioned as one of the starting points when a user is new. But the points could be omitted when these are consecutive edits. When someone had to fix the post again, because someone else messed it up (can happen on parallel edits), then the user should rewarded for the on-going effort. Your example was really strange, that's why I rolled it back, but I don't think that this happens that often to be really concerned about it.

Comment: keep in mind that rep from suggested edits are limited to 1000.  So if someone wanted to abuse this to earn a lot of privileges, they'd still have to get 1000 more points from questions and answers before they get the first significant moderation privilege (review suggested edits)

Comment: A problem is that [reviewers accept edits where](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24567403) [only (often random) words are formatted as code](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24567450) or even only ***adding*** [*"Kindly guide me for this"*](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24536369), [*"thanks in advance.*"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24547917) and similar (a net negative, as time is spent cleaning it up afterwards).